# Date returning different values if time included when using timezones

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get the local time in various timezones for a clock process - for example, now in UK it is 09.07 on 28th December.

I have created two functions to help with this:

```
function dateLocal($timezone='Europe/London') {
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $given = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $output = $given->format("Y-m-d");
    return $output;
}

function dateTimeLocal($timezone='Europe/London') {
    $datetime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $output = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    return $output;
}
```

I am using Honolulu as an example as the date is "yesterday" for the purposes of testing.

If I get the date only it works fine:

```
echo dateLocal("Pacific/Honolulu");
2018-12-27
```

However, if I want to return the date and time then it returns incorrectly:

```
wcho dateTimeLocal("Pacific/Honolulu");
2018-12-28 00:07:23
```

I am expecting it to return:

```
2018-12-27 23:07:23
```

Why are they returning different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the results are different is that the dates in the functions are different. When you do `date('Y-m-d')` the time is set to midnight. However when you do `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` the time is set to whatever the actual time of day is. If you do this:

```
echo $given->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

inside each function, before setting the timezone, you will get results like this:

```
2018-12-28 00:00:00
2018-12-28 10:26:50
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that - however, that being the case why does the dateTimeLocal version still return one hour later than expected?

Comment: @bhttoan that difference is because you're passing a string into the `DateTime` constructor which doesn't reflect the actual current time. Try echoing `$datetime` in `dateTimeLocal` and then passing `NULL` as the `time` parameter in the generation of `$given` and you'll see they are different. You should always use either `NULL` or the string `now` for the time in the constructor if you want the current time.